# using mozrequestfullscreen() with multiple layer canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to go full screen with my canvas which have 3 layers. However whenever i use mozrequestfullscreen method it only works on one layer (because it takes one parameter).
I just wanted to ask is there a way of going full screen with all the layers using mozrequestfullscreen function?

Answer (score 1):

[Using the Fullscreen API](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Put them in a div, request fullscreen on the div:

```
<div class="fullscreen">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Also use selector:-vendor-full-screen to do fullscreen-specific styling:

```
div.fullscreen:-webkit-full-screen {
  /* your styling here */
}

div.fullscreen:-webkit-full-screen canvas {
 /* your styling here */
}
```